# Syncing SharePoint categories with Outlook

Tags: sharepoint-calendar

I've created categories in SharePoint for the purpose of filtering.  However, these categories are only available when you add the event directly onto SharePoint.  For users that prefer to create events via Outlook synchronization, is there a way to add the SharePoint categories to Outlook?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has not provided that functionality.  Some people utilize unused fields that **are** synced for this purpose. YMMV